# how to fit vimeo <iframe> {min-height:100%} not working

Tags: video, iframe, size, screen

I need this simple page with a video, but it has to be fullsize window,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>video</title>
  <style type="text/css">
 body{
      background:#000;
      margin:0;
      width:100%;height:100%;
    }
    iframe{min-height:650px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20881205?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=aebdc2&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="1024" height="765" style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm trying things like:

```
iframe{min-height:100%;height:100%;}
```

But if i don't specify in px won't make any change.. any idea why?

Thanks a lot!

can preview here, if you want http://toniweb.us/video.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.... i checked your preview and it seems ok... in chrome, anyway.

I dont's really understand why you specify in your iframe width and height, and then again in its style attribute. Try deleting width and height, and just keep style.